# Is it possible to gain forever access to a file imported from DocumentPicker?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloud, uidocumentpickervc

I have an app that imports a file (or many files) using the DocumentPickerDelegate. This means that the files imported are likely off of iCloud, Google Drive, etc. I want the app to load any previously selected files on startup, but I'm wondering if this will be possible, since it looks like you lose access to the files once the app closes.

Does anyone know a way around this? For example, are you able to actually copy the imported files to the apps local data?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In the delegate where it gives you the URLs of the selected files you need to make local copies of the files before the delegatecall completes. This is covered in the documentation for UIDocumentPickerController.